# Renaming values in list in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to rename values in a list contained in a pandas column and keep unique values if duplicates exist within the list. Please note that I want to apply this to a pandas column.

```
text                   matches
flowers are red.       [red,yellow,pink]
airplanes are blue.    [blue, indigo]
xxxxxxxx               [orange]
```

I need to replace pink and yellow with red and blue with indigo. Since red and blue already exist in the list, I just want to keep one red and one blue. My code looks like this

```
    df["rename"] = df["matches"].str.replace("pink","red")
```

I need my output to look like this:

```
text                   matches            rename         final
flowers are red.       [red,pink]         [red, red]     [red]
airplanes are blue.    [blue, indigo]     [blue, blue]   [blue] 
xxxxxxxx               [orange]           [orange]       [orange]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean by ". Since red and blue are duplicates in the list"?  Do you mean since "red" exists in "text" column as well as in the "matches" list, you want to keep only 1 occurrence of that value and discard "pink" from the list and dump this in a new column?

Comment: Exactly!  I first need to rename pink to red, then we'll have a list with the word red twice. Since we have a duplicate in the list, I'd like to keep only 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a work around using `apply` and `lambda`

```py
df['rename'] = df['matches'].apply(lambda x: [i.replace('pink', 'red').replace('indigo', 'blue') for i in x])
df['final'] = df['rename'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x))) 

print(df)
```

---

```
                  text         matches            rename     final
0     flowers are red.     [red, pink]        [red, red]     [red]
1  airplanes are blue.  [blue, indigo]      [blue, blue]    [blue]
2             xxxxxxxx        [orange]          [orange]  [orange]
```